# Log search within date range

Tags: text-processing, date

My log file looks like the following sample:

```
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 10/Aug/2020:23:45:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 10/Aug/2020:23:45:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 11/Aug/2020:23:34:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 12/Aug/2020:23:45:43 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 13/Aug/2020:23:43:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 14/Aug/2020:23:33:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
```

I want to search the above entries by specifying a date range, like below:

```
./Logsearch.sh 10/Aug/2020 13/Aug/2020
```

Expected result:

```
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 10/Aug/2020:23:45:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 10/Aug/2020:23:45:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 11/Aug/2020:23:34:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 12/Aug/2020:23:45:43 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 13/Aug/2020:23:43:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
```

How can I do this?

---

Any idea how to write script for my query.May OS is solaris 11.Please provide some sample script.

Comment: Date calculattions are hard. Your best best is to translate dates like "10/Aug/2020" into an internal format (e.g. Unix time, i.e. seconds since the "epoch") that can be directly compared  and use the string format *only* for input and for output. I'd also recommend that you use a better scripting language than bash: python or perl should be much easier to use for this, and many other tasks.

Comment: If you're on a system with `journalctl`, you can use `--since=` and `--until`

Comment: Hi,,i have no idea about journalctl.Can u give some idea to resolve in bash script??

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a standard HTTP access log, so why not use `grep` to match a pattern of the dates you want?

```
$ grep '1[0-3]/Aug/2020' access_log

10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 10/Aug/2020:23:45:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 10/Aug/2020:23:45:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 11/Aug/2020:23:34:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 12/Aug/2020:23:45:43 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 13/Aug/2020:23:43:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
```

The grep pattern '1[0-3]/Aug/2020' uses the range expression [0-3]. This expression matches a single character which can take the values 0,1,2,3. Combine that with the rest of the expression, and you get 10/Aug/2020, 11/Aug/2020, 12/Aug/2020 and 13/Aug/2020 as the possible patterns. `grep` will print out the lines from the log that match these patterns.

Comment: Hello Hexiel,   No. I want to pass an argument date range between like "10/Jul/2020" "15/Aug/2020". So how to grep the lines in between these range in the above log.??any help

Comment: Okay, if your input format is fixed that way, then you need a program that can understand dates and calculate their differences. The GNU `date` program can do this to some extent, but there are limitations. You can also consider using a language better suited to the task, like python.

Comment: Hello Hi, Any other option to achieve this task by looping with grep command??

Comment: It's possible. The `date` command allows strings like '+1 day', so it's possible to use the start date and then keep incrementing until the end date is reached. You could then use `grep` for each date in the range. You may have to do some conversions so that the output from `date` will match the date format in the logs.

Comment: i tried. nothing is working as i want.can u give me script?

Comment: And my OS is solaris 11.Please help

Comment: Sorry, I cannot write an entire script for you. This site simply does not work that way. You should prepare your own script based on the information that I and the others have provided. Once you have a prototype, you can come back and ask specific questions about any problems that you are stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a specialized structured text tool as Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and run

```
mlr --nidx then filter 'strftime(strptime($4,"%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S"),"%Y-%m-%d") >="2020-08-11" && strftime(strptime($4,"%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S"),"%Y-%m-%d") <="2020-08-13"' input.txt
```

to have

```
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 11/Aug/2020:23:34:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 12/Aug/2020:23:45:43 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 13/Aug/2020:23:43:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
```

I have applied a filter to have all between `2020-08-11` and `2020-08-13`

Some notes:

- `--nidx` to set the input and output format (https://bit.ly/3h3UvN3)
- `filter` to apply filter;
- `strftime(strptime($4,"%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S"),"%Y-%m-%d") >="2020-08-11"` is one of the filter. Using `strptime` I set the input date format (`%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S`) of the fourth field (`$4`). Using `strftime` I change the date format in `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: Hi..Sorry we are in big IT sector company..Not allowed to install any external tool in the prod server.Please help to advice in like,AWK,GREP,FIND to achieve the above.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $start_date = DateTime.new("2020-08-11").in-timezone(28800);   \
            my $stop_date  = DateTime.new("2020-08-13").in-timezone(28800);   \
            my @a = lines.map: *.words; my @b = do for @a {  \
                  .[0..2],   \
                  .[3..4].join.subst(/^ (\d**2) \/ (Aug) \/ (\d**4) \: /, {"$2-08-$0T"} )   \
                  .subst(/ (\+\d**2) (\d**2) $/, {"$0:$1"} ).DateTime,  \
                  .[5..*] }; \
            .put if .[1] ~~ $start_date .. $stop_date for @b;'   file
```

#OR:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $start_date = DateTime.new("2020-08-11").in-timezone(28800);  \
            my $stop_date  = DateTime.new("2020-08-13").in-timezone(28800);  \
            my @a = lines.map(*.words).map({   \
                  .[0..2], (   \
                  .[3].subst(/^ (\d**2) \/ (Aug) \/ (\d**4) \: /, {"$2-08-$0T"} ),  \
                  .[4].subst(/ (\+\d**2) (\d**2) $ /, {"$0:$1"} )).join.DateTime,   \ 
                  .[5..*] });  \ 
            .put if .[1] ~~ $start_date .. $stop_date for @a;'   file
```

Above are answers written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Raku has `ISO 8601` DateTime objects built-in.

Briefly, the Date/Time on each line is converted to an `ISO 8601` DateTime object. When each of the `lines` is split into whitespace-separated `words`, the Date/Time elements are found in zero-indexed columns `.[3]` and `.[4]`. These are converted using `subst`itute commands and `join`ed to create `ISO 8601` DateTime objects. Then each line is tested to see whether that DateTime object falls within a desired `$start .. $stop` range.

Sample Input:

```
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 10/Aug/2020:23:45:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 10/Aug/2020:23:45:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 11/Aug/2020:23:34:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 12/Aug/2020:23:45:43 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 13/Aug/2020:23:43:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 14/Aug/2020:23:33:45 +0800 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
```

Sample Output (both code examples):

```
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 2020-08-11T23:34:45+08:00 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
10.434.22.334 - unauthenticated 2020-08-12T23:45:43+08:00 "GET /eai/random.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 74
```

https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org